# Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure stok_yedek, Line 75 Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem; I wrote a SQL trigger and I am getting an error, which is:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure stok_yedek, Line 75
>
> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the
> CONVERT function to run this query.

This is my code:

```
ALTER trigger stok_yedek on dbo.[Instance - Stok (1851)] for insert
as begin
           declare @ParentInstance int
            declare @ParentTemplateConfigurationItem int
           declare @ParentConfigurationItem int
           declare @BaseInstance int
           declare @SortOrder int
           declare @DateCreated datetime
           declare @DateModified datetime
           declare @ModifiedBy int
           declare @RecycleBin tinyint
           declare @Archived tinyint
           declare @OriginalInstance int
           declare @Stok_Adi nchar(100)
           declare @Stok_Grup_Kodu int
           declare @Mevcut_Miktar float
           declare @Model_No nchar(100)
           declare @Grubu int
           declare @Ilgili int
           declare @Marka nchar(100)
           declare @Alt_Grubu int
           declare @Logo_Stok_Kodu nchar(100)
           declare @Depo_Mevcutu float
           declare @Antrepo_Mevcutu float
           declare @Birim int
           declare @New_Drop_Down nvarchar(128)
           declare @Masraf_Merkezi_Kodu float
           declare @Masraf_Merkezi_Kodu2 nchar(100)
           declare @Tipi nchar(100)
           declare @Sogutma_Kapasitesi float
           declare @Marka_Ozel_Kodu int
           declare @Ozel_Kod nchar(100)
           declare @Ozel_Kod2 nchar(100)
           declare @Durumu nvarchar(128)
           declare @Uretici nchar(100)
           declare @Aciklama2 nchar(100)
        select   @ParentInstance=inserted.ParentInstance
            from inserted
        SELECT @ParentTemplateConfigurationItem=inserted.ParentTemplateConfigurationItem
   FROM inserted
     SELECT @ParentConfigurationItem=ParentConfigurationItem
     FROM inserted
      SELECT @BaseInstance=BaseInstance FROM inserted
      SELECT @SortOrder=SortOrder from inserted
      select @DateCreated=DateCreated from inserted
      select @DateModified=DateModified from inserted
      SELECT @ModifiedBy=ModifiedBy FROM inserted
      SELECT @RecycleBin=RecycleBin FROM inserted
     select @Archived=Archived FROM inserted
     SELECT @OriginalInstance=OriginalInstance FROM inserted
     SELECT @Stok_Adi= [Stok Adı (1852)]FROM inserted
     SELECT @Stok_Grup_Kodu=[Stok Grup Kodu (1993)] FROM inserted
     SELECT @Mevcut_Miktar=[Mevcut Miktar (1999)] FROM inserted
    select @Model_No=[Model No (2001)]FROM inserted
    SELECT @Grubu=[Grubu (Özel Kod2) (2002)] from inserted
    select @Ilgili=[İlgili Şirket (2035)] from inserted
    select @Marka=[Markası (2036)] from inserted
    select @Alt_Grubu=[Alt Grubu (Özel Kod3) (2397)] from inserted
    select @Logo_Stok_Kodu=[Logo Stok Kodu (2398)] from inserted
    select @Depo_Mevcutu=[Depo Mevcutu (2487)] from inserted
    select @Antrepo_Mevcutu=[Antrepo Mevcutu (2488)]from inserted
    select @Birim=[Birim (2000)]from inserted
    select @New_Drop_Down=[New Drop Down (3931)]from inserted
    select @Masraf_Merkezi_Kodu=[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3932)]from inserted
    select @Masraf_Merkezi_Kodu2=[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3933)]from inserted
    select @Tipi=[Tipi (3934)] from inserted
    select @Sogutma_Kapasitesi=[Soğutma Kapasitesi (3935)] from inserted
    select @Marka_Ozel_Kodu=inserted.[Marka (Özel Kodu) (4046)] from inserted
    select @Ozel_Kod=[Özel Kod4 (4053)] from inserted
    select @Ozel_Kod2=[Özel Kod5 (4054)]from inserted
    select @Durumu=[Durumu (4247)] from inserted
    select @Uretici=[Üretici Kodu (4302)] from inserted
    select @Aciklama2=[Açıklama-2 (4303)] from inserted

  INSERT INTO [EGITIM_01].dbo.[Instance - Stok (1851)]
           ([ParentInstance]
           ,[ParentTemplateConfigurationItem]
           ,[ParentConfigurationItem]
           ,[BaseInstance]
           ,[SortOrder]
           ,[DateCreated]
           ,[DateModified]
           ,[ModifiedBy]
           ,[RecycleBin]
           ,[Archived]
           ,[OriginalInstance]
           ,[Stok Adı (1852)]
           ,[Stok Grup Kodu (1993)]
           ,[Mevcut Miktar (1999)]
           ,[Model No (2001)]
           ,[Grubu (Özel Kod2) (2002)]
           ,[İlgili Şirket (2035)]
           ,[Markası (2036)]
           ,[Alt Grubu (Özel Kod3) (2397)]
           ,[Logo Stok Kodu (2398)]
           ,[Depo Mevcutu (2487)]
           ,[Antrepo Mevcutu (2488)]
           ,[Birim (2000)]
           ,[New Drop Down (3931)]
           ,[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3932)]
           ,[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3933)]
           ,[Tipi (3934)]
           ,[Soğutma Kapasitesi (3935)]
           ,[Marka (Özel Kodu) (4046)]
           ,[Özel Kod4 (4053)]
           ,[Özel Kod5 (4054)]
           ,[Durumu (4247)]
           ,[Üretici Kodu (4302)]
           ,[Açıklama-2 (4303)])
     VALUES
           (@ParentInstance,@ParentInstance,@ParentTemplateConfigurationItem
     ,@ParentConfigurationItem,@BaseInstance,@SortOrder,@DateCreated
     ,@DateModified,@ModifiedBy,@RecycleBin,@OriginalInstance,@Stok_Adi,
     @Stok_Grup_Kodu,@Mevcut_Miktar,@Model_No,@Grubu,@Ilgili,
     @Marka,@Alt_Grubu,@Logo_Stok_Kodu,@Depo_Mevcutu,@Antrepo_Mevcutu,
     @Birim,@New_Drop_Down,@Masraf_Merkezi_Kodu,@Masraf_Merkezi_Kodu2,@Tipi
     ,@Sogutma_Kapasitesi,@Marka,@Ozel_Kod,@Ozel_Kod2,@Durumu,@Uretici
     ,@Aciklama2
     )  
         if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION InProc;
-- There is no BEGIN TRAN statement after this statement. However there is no error 266 either.
        PRINT 'In proc commit: ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT as char(1));
    END
    else
        print @@error
    end
  INSERT INTO [Ramazan_Test].[dbo].[stok_yedek]
           ([ParentInstance]
           ,[ParentTemplateConfigurationItem]
           ,[ParentConfigurationItem]
           ,[BaseInstance]
           ,[SortOrder]
           ,[DateCreated]
           ,[DateModified]
           ,[ModifiedBy]
           ,[RecycleBin]
           ,[Archived]
           ,[OriginalInstance]
           ,[Stok_Adi]
           ,[Stok Grup Kodu (1993)]
           ,[Mevcut Miktar (1999)]
           ,[Model No (2001)]
           ,[Grubu (Özel Kod2) (2002)]
           ,[İlgili Şirket (2035)]
           ,[Markası (2036)]
           ,[Alt Grubu (Özel Kod3) (2397)]
           ,[Logo Stok Kodu (2398)]
           ,[Depo Mevcutu (2487)]
           ,[Antrepo Mevcutu (2488)]
           ,[Birim (2000)]
           ,[New Drop Down (3931)]
           ,[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3932)]
           ,[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3933)]
           ,[Tipi (3934)]
           ,[Soğutma Kapasitesi (3935)]
           ,[Marka (Özel Kodu) (4046)]
           ,[Özel Kod4 (4053)]
           ,[Özel Kod5 (4054)]
           ,[Durumu (4247)]
           ,[Üretici Kodu (4302)]
           ,[Açıklama-2 (4303)])
     VALUES
           (@ParentInstance,@ParentInstance,@ParentTemplateConfigurationItem
     ,@ParentConfigurationItem,@BaseInstance,@SortOrder,@DateCreated
     ,@DateModified,@ModifiedBy,@RecycleBin,@OriginalInstance,@Stok_Adi,
     @Stok_Grup_Kodu,@Mevcut_Miktar,@Model_No,@Grubu,@Ilgili,
     @Marka,@Alt_Grubu,@Logo_Stok_Kodu,@Depo_Mevcutu,@Antrepo_Mevcutu,
     @Birim,@New_Drop_Down,@Masraf_Merkezi_Kodu,@Masraf_Merkezi_Kodu2,@Tipi
     ,@Sogutma_Kapasitesi,@Marka,@Ozel_Kod,@Ozel_Kod2,@Durumu,@Uretici
     ,@Aciklama2
     )
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Holy inefficient and bad code. You do NOT need to run a separate select statement to set variables for each column. The REAL issue here is your trigger assumes there will only ever be a single row in the inserted table. This is not how sql server works. You need to change the logic by doing a single insert statement and forget about using scalar variables in a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `datetime` variable values to `INT` and then `INSERT`.

e.g.:

```
DECLARE @DateCreated datetime='2015-06-2 11:59:59'
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar(20),@DateCreated,112) as INT)
```

Refer to the above code while inserting `@DateCreated`, `@DateModified` you can use:

```
CAST(CONVERT(varchar(20),@DateCreated,112) as INT),     
CAST(CONVERT(varchar(20),@DateModified ,112) as INT)
```

Comment: U can use BIGINT datatype instead if overflow is happening

Comment: you mean it "cast(CONVERT(varchar(20),@DateModified ,112) as bigint)"

Answer (score 1):

I did a little bit of cleanup job on your code for you. You could save yourself from some unnecessary headaches in the future by keeping your code simple and clean like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER stok_yedek ON dbo.[Instance - Stok (1851)]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [EGITIM_01].dbo.[Instance - Stok (1851)] (
        [ParentInstance]
        ,[ParentTemplateConfigurationItem]
        ,[ParentConfigurationItem]
        ,[BaseInstance]
        ,[SortOrder]
        ,[DateCreated]
        ,[DateModified]
        ,[ModifiedBy]
        ,[RecycleBin]
        ,[Archived]
        ,[OriginalInstance]
        ,[Stok Adı (1852)]
        ,[Stok Grup Kodu (1993)]
        ,[Mevcut Miktar (1999)]
        ,[Model No (2001)]
        ,[Grubu (Özel Kod2) (2002)]
        ,[İlgili Şirket (2035)]
        ,[Markası (2036)]
        ,[Alt Grubu (Özel Kod3) (2397)]
        ,[Logo Stok Kodu (2398)]
        ,[Depo Mevcutu (2487)]
        ,[Antrepo Mevcutu (2488)]
        ,[Birim (2000)]
        ,[New Drop Down (3931)]
        ,[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3932)]
        ,[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3933)]
        ,[Tipi (3934)]
        ,[Soğutma Kapasitesi (3935)]
        ,[Marka (Özel Kodu) (4046)]
        ,[Özel Kod4 (4053)]
        ,[Özel Kod5 (4054)]
        ,[Durumu (4247)]
        ,[Üretici Kodu (4302)]
        ,[Açıklama-2 (4303)]
        )
    SELECT i.[ParentInstance]
        ,i.[ParentTemplateConfigurationItem]
        ,i.[ParentConfigurationItem]
        ,i.[BaseInstance]
        ,i.[SortOrder]
        ,i.[DateCreated]
        ,i.[DateModified]
        ,i.[ModifiedBy]
        ,i.[RecycleBin]
        ,i.[Archived]
        ,i.[OriginalInstance]
        ,i.[Stok Adı (1852)]
        ,i.[Stok Grup Kodu (1993)]
        ,i.[Mevcut Miktar (1999)]
        ,i.[Model No (2001)]
        ,i.[Grubu (Özel Kod2) (2002)]
        ,i.[İlgili Şirket (2035)]
        ,i.[Markası (2036)]
        ,i.[Alt Grubu (Özel Kod3) (2397)]
        ,i.[Logo Stok Kodu (2398)]
        ,i.[Depo Mevcutu (2487)]
        ,i.[Antrepo Mevcutu (2488)]
        ,i.[Birim (2000)]
        ,i.[New Drop Down (3931)]
        ,i.[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3932)]
        ,i.[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3933)]
        ,i.[Tipi (3934)]
        ,i.[Soğutma Kapasitesi (3935)]
        ,i.[Marka (Özel Kodu) (4046)]
        ,i.[Özel Kod4 (4053)]
        ,i.[Özel Kod5 (4054)]
        ,i.[Durumu (4247)]
        ,i.[Üretici Kodu (4302)]
        ,i.[Açıklama-2 (4303)]
    FROM inserted i

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION InProc;

        -- There is no BEGIN TRAN statement after this statement. However there is no error 266 either.
        PRINT 'In proc commit: ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS CHAR(1));
    END
    ELSE
        PRINT @@error
END

BEGIN
INSERT INTO [Ramazan_Test].[dbo].[stok_yedek] (
    [ParentInstance]
    ,[ParentTemplateConfigurationItem]
    ,[ParentConfigurationItem]
    ,[BaseInstance]
    ,[SortOrder]
    ,[DateCreated]
    ,[DateModified]
    ,[ModifiedBy]
    ,[RecycleBin]
    ,[Archived]
    ,[OriginalInstance]
    ,[Stok_Adi]
    ,[Stok Grup Kodu (1993)]
    ,[Mevcut Miktar (1999)]
    ,[Model No (2001)]
    ,[Grubu (Özel Kod2) (2002)]
    ,[İlgili Şirket (2035)]
    ,[Markası (2036)]
    ,[Alt Grubu (Özel Kod3) (2397)]
    ,[Logo Stok Kodu (2398)]
    ,[Depo Mevcutu (2487)]
    ,[Antrepo Mevcutu (2488)]
    ,[Birim (2000)]
    ,[New Drop Down (3931)]
    ,[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3932)]
    ,[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3933)]
    ,[Tipi (3934)]
    ,[Soğutma Kapasitesi (3935)]
    ,[Marka (Özel Kodu) (4046)]
    ,[Özel Kod4 (4053)]
    ,[Özel Kod5 (4054)]
    ,[Durumu (4247)]
    ,[Üretici Kodu (4302)]
    ,[Açıklama-2 (4303)]
    )
SELECT ins.[ParentInstance]
    ,ins.[ParentTemplateConfigurationItem]
    ,ins.[ParentConfigurationItem]
    ,ins.[BaseInstance]
    ,ins.[SortOrder]
    ,ins.[DateCreated]
    ,ins.[DateModified]
    ,ins.[ModifiedBy]
    ,ins.[RecycleBin]
    ,ins.[Archived]
    ,ins.[OriginalInstance]
    ,ins.[Stok_Adi]
    ,ins.[Stok Grup Kodu (1993)]
    ,ins.[Mevcut Miktar (1999)]
    ,ins.[Model No (2001)]
    ,ins.[Grubu (Özel Kod2) (2002)]
    ,ins.[İlgili Şirket (2035)]
    ,ins.[Markası (2036)]
    ,ins.[Alt Grubu (Özel Kod3) (2397)]
    ,ins.[Logo Stok Kodu (2398)]
    ,ins.[Depo Mevcutu (2487)]
    ,ins.[Antrepo Mevcutu (2488)]
    ,ins.[Birim (2000)]
    ,ins.[New Drop Down (3931)]
    ,ins.[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3932)]
    ,ins.[Masraf Merkezi Kodu (3933)]
    ,ins.[Tipi (3934)]
    ,ins.[Soğutma Kapasitesi (3935)]
    ,ins.[Marka (Özel Kodu) (4046)]
    ,ins.[Özel Kod4 (4053)]
    ,ins.[Özel Kod5 (4054)]
    ,ins.[Durumu (4247)]
    ,ins.[Üretici Kodu (4302)]
    ,ins.[Açıklama-2 (4303)]
FROM inserted ins

END
```

Comment: You will need to add `BEGIN TRAN` before commit.